# How to delete a "text tag" with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Please tell me how to remove the text tag from html like this and leave the child element.

```
<text _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c2="">
    <p>sample text</p>
</text>
<image>
    <figure>
        <img alt="" src="xxxxx.jpg"/>
    </figure>
</image>
```

I want to convert it as follows

```
<p>sample text</p>
<image>
    <figure>
        <img alt="" src="xxxxx.jpg"/>
    </figure>
</image>
```

I tried the following method, but an error `'str' object has no attribute 'unwrap'` occurred.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '<text _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c2="">
             <p>sample text</p>
           </text>
           <image>
             <figure>
               <img alt="" src="xxxxx.jpg"/>
             </figure>
           </image>'

while (content.text):
    content.text.unwrap()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get "unwrapped" element like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '<text _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c2=""><p>sample text</p></text><image><figure><img alt="" src="xxxxx.jpg"/></figure></image>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    p.parent.unwrap()
    print(p.parent)  # prints <p>sample text</p><image><figure><img alt="" src="xxxxx.jpg"/></figure></image>
```

From the code you provided, it seems like you are not using BeautifulSoup at all, instead you are trying to use `unwrap` method on a plain string, therefore the error you mentioned.
In case you are using BeatifulSoup, please provide rest of the code you are using to parse the HTML.

Comment: Sorry for lack of description.
I want to know how to respond when there are other elements in content.
I updated my question.

Comment: My example should work for your updated case too. It should return `<p>sample text</p><image><figure><img alt="" src="xxxxx.jpg"/></figure></image>`. I updated my answer to clarify the problem you have.